# Is there a way to have unchanging DIFFERENT values in a row?

Tags: list, column

If I want to have a column, for example "`start date`", and want the values to always be the same in each row (ex. `row 1 = "12/20/93"` `row 2 = "10/19/89"`, etc.) is there a way that you can keep these dates the same every time the list is opened????

Comment: what you means by same date? do you want, once date entered then no body can change it, is this your question?

Comment: Based on your question, I have understood that you need a column in a list. And you need to maintain certain values in it which do not get changed, right? 
Also in your explanation you mentioned that each row should have same values but your example says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with all the values you want populated and then save that as a template (check 'save content'). Once you've done that, you can create a new list that is of this type and has all of these pre-filled rows.